# How to display a long content in the webite in asp.net c# using sql server 2005

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I want to make a demo web application... something like wikipedia
I want that when user click on one word or images than related content of that word should display in other page.

Content can be long text or images
So I want to know how to store and  that content in database

I have used the  code from below link:

- [Retrieve files from SQL Server 2005 using Asp.net](http://csharp-guide.blogspot.in/2012/06/retrieve-files-from-sql-server-2005.html)

But i want to display file content in my website...
Please give suggestion ...how to store content in the database(datatype of content)

Can i used wordpress for this?... but i have no idea about work press

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **VARCHAR(MAX)** to store largedata in database because it can store **2,147,483,647** characters..For displaying u can use divs and tables in asp.net...and if u have images,store those in your physical folder(a folder in ur application) and store the **imagepath** in ur database.

Answer (score 3):

By the description, you want to store alot of text data in the database. I will suggest you the following

> VARCHAR(MAX) if it's all going to be ascii-based, say for text with
>   English content
>
> NVARCHAR(MAX) if the text could contain any special charachters (eg.
>   Japanese, Arabic, etc.)
>
> NVARCHAR will double your storage use as it uses double the amount of
>   space as VARCHAR.